# Reference Request: Proof of Frobenius Density Theorem

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am looking for a proof of the Frobenius Density Theorem other than the one given in Gerald J Janusz's Algebraic Number Fields. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never found the time to clean up the notes for an introduction to class field theory from 2006, but for what it's worth, these 
[notes](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/cft/cfb.pdf) contain a step-by-step derivation of the Frobenius density theorem.

Comment: Though that pdf seems to often suppose unramified extension, how can we remove this assumption?

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer . I was wondering if you have any updated version? They look very nice but some little chapters are incomplete I think.